# python attribute error while calling method from a different class

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have two classes in a package.

```
class a(object):

    def func1(self,param):
        return param.split(',')

    def func2(self,param):
        a=self.func1(param).upper()
        return a


from package_name.file_name import a
class b(object):

    def func3(self,param):
        b=a.func2(param)
        return b
```

When i call the func3, attribute error is returned which specifies that class b has no atttribute func2.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is occurring because 'a' needs to be called from inside 'b' to access the attribute. Instead of saying class_name, tell it the name of the class, which is 'a'.

For

```
def func3(self,param):
        b=class_name.func2(param)
        return b
```

Try

```
def func3(self,param):
        b=a.func2(param)
        return b
```

Comment: apologies, it should have been "a"  instead of "class_name.

Comment: The issue is still stands.

Comment: are package_name and file_name defined somewhere?

Comment: b=class_name.func2(param)  still needs to be b=a.func2(param)

Comment: yes in the __init__ file of the package. Both the classes reside in the same package.

Comment: create an object of classes and then access its functions like, x=  b()
x.func3()